# A basic custom hook for increment and decrement but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am just trying to apply a basic custom hook but it gives an error that but it gives an error as
React Hook "useState" is called in function "usecount" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function.

```
import { useState } from 'react'

function usecount() {

const [count,setCount] = useState(0)

const increment = () =>{
    setCount(prev => prev + 1)
}

const decrement = () =>{
    setCount(prev => prev - 1)
}

const reset = () =>{
    setCount(0)
}
return [count,increment,decrement,reset]
}

export default usecount
```

Comment: Looks good. Can you share on how you use it?

Answer (score 5):

This is because your component name is in the lowercase.

> **Component's name should be in camelCase.**

Check this CodeSandBox link https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-http-q57iy?file=/src/customHook.js and try to paste the code mentioned below and you will see that by changing the component's name that error:

> React Hook "useState" is called in function "usecount" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function.

will go away.

```
import { useState } from 'react'

function useCount() {
    const [count,setCount] = useState(0);

    const increment = () =>{
        setCount(prev => prev + 1);
    }

    const decrement = () =>{
        setCount(prev => prev - 1);
    }

    const reset = () =>{
        setCount(0);
    }

    return [count,increment,decrement,reset];
}
export default useCount
```

Comment: @AlexWayne checkout this code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-http-q57iy?file=/src/customHook.js. Then try to paste my code mentioned above and check that error goes away

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the question! This is exactly the eslint warning the questioner is trying to fix. Upvoted! :)